# we are aware when one of our cognitive biases is activated

Tags: clauses

> It is important that we are aware when one of our cognitive biases is activated and make a conscious choice to overcome that bias.

'when one of our cognitive biases is activated' is a adverbial clause or noun clause?

If we send the clause to the back "we are aware and make a conscious choice to overcome that bias when one of our cognitive biases is activated." and still idiomatic, then it's adverbial.

What do you think?

Comment: Your text is badly phrased, because it could easily be interpreted as ***We are** aware when one of our cognitive biases is activated. This **fact** is important.* Changing ***that we are...*** to ***that we should be...*** (or even more explicitly, ***that we should try to be...***) would sort that problem out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers noun or adverbial ?

Comment: I'm not sure that's a meaningful question. My first thought would be that *any* expression starting with ***when*** must *by definition* be "adverbial". But you might think that the highlighted part of ***When you go to bed** IS up to your mother* must be a "noun" because it's serving as the subject of the verb IS. Me, I think labels like that are usually worthless in any context where it's not blindingly obvious which label applies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think if the sentence "we are aware of when  one of our cognitive biases is activated" makes sense, then it's a noun clause. If not, then it can move to the front or to the end of the sentence because it's adverbial.

Comment: Well, it's certainly possible to rearrange your cited text to ***When one of our cognitive biases is activated** it is important that we [blah blah]*, so it sounds to me as if you'd think that's an adverbial usage. Whereas in ***When one of our cognitive biases is activated** IS often difficult to detect* the highlighted text is the syntactic subject, so you might want to call it a "noun phrase".